# DocumentReference return sensitive data - Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a "post" and "user" collection, in the Post I attached "userId" as a reference to the user document

Everything works perfectly except the get().data() method I call on the Post document exposes all sensitive data (which I will send to the clients via Express server)

```
const ref = (await firestore.doc(...).get()).data()
  res.json({
    success: true,
    msg: ref,
  });
```

This is what I get in the ref variable:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "msg": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "userId": {
      "_firestore": {
        "_settings": {
          "credentials": {
            "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", <--- Big problem
            "client_email": "..."
          },
          "projectId": "cpanel-9ac21",
          "firebaseVersion": "8.9.0",
          "libName": "gccl",
          "libVersion": "3.3.3 fire/8.9.0",
          "servicePath": "firestore.googleapis.com",
          "port": 443,
          "clientConfig": {},
          "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore"
          ]
        },
        "_settingsFrozen": true,
        "_serializer": {},
        "_projectId": "cpanel-9ac21",
        "_lastSuccessfulRequest": 1578712168345,
        "_backoffSettings": {
          "initialDelayMs": 100,
          "maxDelayMs": 60000,
          "backoffFactor": 1.3
        },
        "_preferTransactions": false,
        "_clientPool": {
          "concurrentOperationLimit": 100,
          "maxIdleClients": 1,
          "activeClients": {},
          "terminated": false
        }
      },
      "_path": {
        "segments": [
          "users",
          "TXMF00S2PugwdwO5ge3vwQA6pV63"
        ]
      }
    },
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

I also searched on the Internet but unfortunately didn't find the answer/solution

Comment: Just remove sensitive properties from `ref` object before sending it to client. Do not send whole response to the client.

Comment: Technically I can remove the "userId" prop when sending to the clients but it's not dynamic. What if I have "userId", "postId", ...etc I have to remove it manually each time. Is there a way to remove a property if it is a DocumentReference object?

Comment: Yes, its quite normal, you get a lot of stuff from Firestore, which your service may need but those inflammations will not be helpful to your clients unless there is a business need to do this

Comment: Are you writing the `_firestore` data into the document yourself? Or are you saying that this is something that Firestore returns in the code you shared, but it is not present in the stored document?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you showed **exactly** what's in this document.  What are the fields and their types?  A screenshot would be good.  Also please show what specifically you think should be returned to the client from that document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it, so basically firestore will return DocumentReference instance. All I need is to transform to document's path:

```
const purifyData = (data) => {
  const purifiedData = Object.keys(data).reduce((accumulator, prop) => {
    const propData = data[prop];
    if (propData instanceof firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) {
      accumulator[prop] = propData.path;
    } else {
      accumulator[prop] = propData;
    }

    return accumulator;
  }, {});

  return purifiedData;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With Firestore, the typical way to separate public from private data is to put them in different collections.  So, if you have a post, and you need to divide the public and private data, you might have two collections: "posts-public/{id}" and "posts-private/{id}".  Or you might use subcollections under the same id: "posts/{id}/public" and "posts/{id}/private".

Once you have the collections split, you can also protect them with different security rules that allow access to only what the user should be able to see.  If you don't want the user to see any private data at all, then that collection should simply not grant access.

Comment: I think OP may be talking about the `_settings`. I'm not sure that is part of the document's data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Wouldn't calling data() just return only the data in the document?

Comment: It *should*. But there's so much system metadata in there in the post, that I'm wondering if it is somehow coming from Firestore. It might be worth trying to repro..